# Spring MVC 406 error

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I have written a Spring MVC application which displays a model in XML format.Its building well.But its giving me a 406 error which looks something like this

HTTP Status 406 -

---

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

Please advice thanks in advance

Comment: I know this was a while ago but can you add the method signature, including annotations, to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the Accept header in your request:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.My request mapping statement looks like this.                                    RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET) I tried adding both produces as well as accept as a parameter for Request Mapping but it didnt work.Can you suggest a way.